# overloading [][] operators in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a matrix 3x3 class in c++.

glm::mat3 provides access to matrix data through the `[][] operator` syntax.
e.g. `myMatrix[0][0] = 1.0f;`  would set the first row, first column entry to **1.0f**.

I'd like to provide similar access.  How can I overload the `[][] operator`s?

I've tried the following, but I get errors:

> operator name must be declared as a function

```
const real operator[][](int row, int col) const
{
    // should really throw an exception for out of bounds indices
    return ((row >= 0 && row <= 2) && (col >= 0 && col <= 2)) ? _data[row][col] : 0.0f;
}
```

What's the correct way to overload this operator?

Comment: If you can deal with matrix(x,y) syntax, go with that. Our codebase couldn't since we wanted to be able to quickly swap legacy code using 2-dimensional arrays to use our matrix classes instead. A way that sacrifices some safety but quickly achieves what you want is to do:

const real* operator[](int row) const
{
    return _data[row];
};

This sacrifices the ability to do bounds-checking on the result when fetching a column, however, so a proxy object could be used instead for a safer result.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to interchange my code with the glm code, just by changing the namespace used, so I can't go with the operator().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no operator `[][]`, so you need to overload the `[]` operator twice: once on the matrix, returning a [*surrogate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object for the row, and once for the returned surrogate row:

```
// Matrix's operator[]
const row_proxy operator[](int row) const
{
    return row_proxy(this, row);
}
// Proxy's operator[]
const real operator[](int col) const
{
    // Proxy stores a pointer to matrix and the row passed into the first [] operator
    return ((this->row >= 0 && this->row <= 2) && (col >= 0 && col <= 2)) ? this->matrix->_data[this->row][col] : 0.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It would be easier to make the method `double operator() (int row, int col) const`.  Instead of `matrix[i][j]` you just say `matrix(i,j)`.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, for multiple argument you want to use `operator()`, not `operator[]`.

Hm, in case it wasn't obvious, there is no `operator[][]` in C++. It's just `operator[]` applied twice. Which means that *if* you want that notation, then you have to let the first one return a result (indexable thing or proxy) that the second can be applied to.

The code below sketches some approaches, choose what you like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template< int n >
int& dummy() { static int elem = n; return elem; }

struct Mat1
{
    int operator() ( int const x, int const y ) const
    { return dummy<1>(); }

    int& operator() ( int const x, int const y )
    { return dummy<1>(); }

    Mat1( int, int ) {}
};

struct Mat2
{
    int at( int const x, int const y ) const
    { return dummy<2>(); }

    int& at( int const x, int const y )
    { return dummy<2>(); }

    Mat2( int, int ) {}
};

struct Mat3
{
    struct At { At( int x, int y ) {} };

    int operator[]( At const i ) const
    { return dummy<3>(); }

    int& operator[]( At const i )
    { return dummy<3>(); }

    Mat3( int, int ) {}
};

class Mat4
{
protected:
    int get( int const x, int const y ) const
    { return dummy<4>(); }

    void set( int const x, int const y, int const v ) {}

    class AssignmentProxy
    {
    private:
        Mat4*   pMat_;
        int     x_;
        int     y_;
    public:
        void operator=( int const v ) const
        { pMat_->set( x_, y_, v ); }

        int value() const { return pMat_->get( x_, y_ ); }
        operator int () const { return value(); }

        AssignmentProxy( Mat4& mat, int const x, int const y )
            : pMat_( &mat ), x_( x ), y_( y )
        {}
    };

public:
    int operator()( int const x, int const y ) const
    { return get( x, y ); }

    AssignmentProxy operator()( int const x, int const y )
    { return AssignmentProxy( *this, x, y ); }

    Mat4( int, int ) {}
};

class Mat5
{
protected:
    int at( int const x, int const y ) const
    { return dummy<4>(); }

    int& at( int const x, int const y )
    { return dummy<5>(); }

    class RowReadAccess
    {
    private:
        Mat5 const* pMat_;
        int         y_;

    public:
        int operator[]( int const x ) const
        {
            return pMat_->at( x, y_ );
        }

        RowReadAccess( Mat5 const& m, int const y )
            : pMat_( &m ), y_( y )
        {}
    };

    class RowRWAccess
    {
    private:
        Mat5*   pMat_;
        int     y_;

    public:
        int operator[]( int const x ) const
        {
            return pMat_->at( x, y_ );
        }

        int& operator[]( int const x )
        {
            return pMat_->at( x, y_ );
        }

        RowRWAccess( Mat5& m, int const y )
            : pMat_( &m ), y_( y )
        {}
    };

public:
    RowReadAccess operator[]( int const y ) const
    { return RowReadAccess( *this, y ); }

    RowRWAccess operator[]( int const y )
    { return RowRWAccess( *this, y ); }

    Mat5( int, int ) {}
};

struct Mat6
{
private:
    std::vector<int>    elems_;
    int                 width_;
    int                 height_;

    int indexFor( int const x, int const y ) const
    {
        return y*width_ + x;
    }

public:
    int const* operator[]( int const y ) const
    {
        return &elems_[indexFor( 0, y )];
    }

    int* operator[]( int const y )
    {
        return &elems_[indexFor( 0, y )];
    }

    Mat6( int const w, int const h )
        : elems_( w*h, 6 ), width_( w ), height_( h )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    enum{ w = 1024, h = 1024 };
    typedef Mat3::At At;

    Mat1 m1( w, h );
    Mat2 m2( w, h );
    Mat3 m3( w, h );
    Mat4 m4( w, h );
    Mat5 m5( w, h );
    Mat6 m6( w, h );

    wcout
        << m1( 100, 200 )       // No fuss simple, but exposes element ref.
        << m2.at( 100, 200 )    // For those who don't like operators.
        << m3[At( 100, 200)]    // If you really want square brackets mnemonic.
        << m4( 100, 200 )       // Hides element ref by using assignment proxy.
        << m5[200][100]         // Ditto but with square brackets (more complex).
        << m6[200][100]         // The minimum fuss square brackets, exposes elem ref.
        << endl;
}
```

Oh well I discovered after posting that code that I haven't fully hidden the internal storage for `Mat5`: it needs an extra proxy level, as in `Mat4`. So that approach is really complex. I wouldn't do it (`Mat1` is nice and easy I think), but some folks think proxys are cool, and data hiding even more cool…

Summing up, there is no “the” correct way to overload `operator[]`. There are many ways (as illustrated by the code above), each with some trade-offs. And generally you’re better off using `operator()`, because as opposed to `operator[]` it can take any number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `[][]` operator. The way GLM does it is by returning a `vec3&` from the first `[]`. `vec3` has its own `[]` operator overload. So it's two separate `operator[]`s on two separate classes.

This is also how GLSL works. The first `[]` gets the column as a vector. The second takes the vector and gets the value from it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `foo[1][2]` is really interpreted as `(foo[1])[2]`, i.e. the `[]` operator is applied twice in succession starting with the variable `foo`. There is no `[][]` operator to be overloaded.