# How can I return the Index of a row in a 2D array with a function?

Tags: c++

I want to design a modular program that analyzes a year's worth of rainfall data. In addition to main, the program should have a `getData` function that accepts the total rainfall for each of 12 months from the user and stores it in a 2-D array of type double. It should also have four value-returning functions that compute and return to main the `totalRainfall`, `averageRainfall`, `driestMonth`, and `wettestMonth`. These last two functions return the number of the month with the lowest and highest rainfall amounts, not the amount of rain that fell those months. Notice that this month number can be used to obtain the amount of rain that fell those months. This information should be used either by main or by a `displayReport` function called by main to print a summary rainfall report similar to the following:

Here is the code I have written, I continue getting 0 returned I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
const int months = 12;
const int rain = 1;

void getData(double[months][rain], int, int);
double totalRainfall(double[months][rain], int, int);
double averageRain(double, int);
double driestMonth(double[months][rain], int, int);

int main()
{   
    double totalRain;
    double averageRainfall;
    int leastMonth;
    double rainfall[months][rain];
    
    getData(rainfall, months, rain);
    totalRain = totalRainfall(rainfall, months, rain);
    averageRainfall = averageRain(totalRain, months);
    leastMonth = driestMonth(rainfall, months, rain);
    
    cout << averageRainfall << endl;
    cout << leastMonth;
}

void getData(double rainfall[months][rain], int months, int rain)
{   
    double rainAmount;
    
    for(int row = 0; row < months; row++)
    {   
        for(int column = 0; column < rain; column++)
        {
            cout << "enter rain for month " << (row+1) << "--->";
            cin >> rainAmount;

            while(rainAmount <= 0)
            {
                cout << "rainfall must be greater then 0" << endl;
                cout << "enter rainfall ---> ";
                cin >> rainAmount;
            }

            rainfall[row][column] = rainAmount;
        }
    }
}

double totalRainfall(double rainfall[months][rain], int months, int rain)
{   
    double totalRain = 0;

    for (int column = 0; column < months; column++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < rain; row++)
        {
            totalRain += rainfall[column][row];
        }
    }
    return totalRain;
}

double averageRain(double totalRain, int months)
{   
    double averageRainfall;
    averageRainfall = totalRain / months;
    return averageRainfall;
}

double driestMonth(double rainfall[months][rain], int months, int rain)
{
    double leastRainMonth = rainfall[0][0];
    int leastMonth;
    
    for(int row = 0; row < months; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < rain; rain++)
        {
            if(rainfall[row][column] < leastMonth)
            {
                leastRainMonth = rainfall[row][column];
                leastMonth = row;
            }   
        }   
    }
    
    return leastMonth;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`

Answer (score 1):

it looks like this is an assignment that you need to find yourself, so I'm not going to give you code. you can declare an `dbl_array[sizex][sizey];` but there are two things:

The structure `double dbl_array[sizex][sizey]` is an array of `sizex` pointers to arrays of `sizey` doubles. So your data structure may not be the 2D array you need to produce. My guess is that would be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657811).

The other thing is the difference between passing variables to functions by value *vs.* by reference. You are passing your functions by value, so changes made to the input array are lost when your function ends.

That is a pretty important concept that you probably want to understand first, see [here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/passing-array-to-function-in-c-cpp/#call-by-value-&-call-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

In the function `driestMonth`:

- You should initialize `leastMonth`, or the indeterminate uninitialized value may be returned.
- You should increment `column` instead of `rain` in the inner loop.
- You should compare `rainfall[row][column]` with `leastRainMonth`, not `leastMonth`.

Fixed code:

```cpp
double driestMonth(double rainfall[months][rain], int months, int rain)
{
    double leastRainMonth = rainfall[0][0];
    int leastMonth = 0; // initialize this
    
    for(int row = 0; row < months; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < rain; column++) // increment proper thing
        {
            if(rainfall[row][column] < leastRainMonth) // compare with proper thing
            {
                leastRainMonth = rainfall[row][column];
                leastMonth = row;
            }   
        }   
    }
    
    return leastMonth;
}
```